# Getting segmentation fault when reading 2kb txt file (c)

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, fopen

Following is a code that reads from a file and saves each string of said file to a binary search tree. It works fine for txt files that are 1KB however when trying to use a larger file (2kb) i get segmentation fault.

```css
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h> 
#include <string.h> 

typedef struct listNode ListNode;


struct listNode {
  int id;
  ListNode *next;
};

typedef struct treeNode TreeNode;


struct treeNode {
  char *word;
  char *key;
  int freq;
  ListNode *head;   
  TreeNode *left;
  TreeNode *right;
};

TreeNode* insertItem(TreeNode *root, char *gword);
void printTreeInorder(TreeNode *v);
void searchforexist(TreeNode *root, char *key);

#define MAX 25
int main()
{
   
    char word[MAX];
    TreeNode *root = NULL;
    
    
   
    FILE *fp=fopen("input.txt","r");

     if (fp!=NULL)
    {
      
        while (fscanf(fp,"%s \n",word) != EOF)
         {
              
            root = insertItem(root,word); 

          if (strcmp(word, "eof")==0)
            break;
          }
     }
    fclose(fp);


    printTreeInorder(root);
    printf("\n");
   
    return 0;
}


TreeNode* insertItem(TreeNode *root, char *gword)
{
   TreeNode *v = root;  
   TreeNode *pv = NULL; 
   while (v != NULL)
   {
      pv = v;
      int comp = strcmp(gword, v->word);
      if (comp < 0) v=v->left;
      else if (comp > 0) v=v->right;
      else
      {
         
          
         char *key=v->word;
         searchforexist(root,key);
          return root;
      }
   }

   TreeNode *tmp = (TreeNode *) malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
   tmp->word=strdup(gword); 
   tmp->left=tmp->right=NULL;
   tmp->freq=1;
   

   if (root != NULL)
   {
      if (strcmp(gword, pv->word) < 0) pv->left=tmp;
         else pv->right=tmp;
   } else root=tmp;

   return root;

}



void searchforexist(TreeNode *root, char *key)
{
   if (root == NULL || root->key == key) 
       root->freq ++; 
     
    
    if (root->key < key) 
       searchforexist(root->right, key); 
  
    
     searchforexist(root->left, key); 
 } 




void printTreeInorder(TreeNode *v)
{
    if (v==NULL) return;

    printf("(");
    printTreeInorder(v->left);
    printf(")");

    printf(" %.4s ", v->word);

    printf("(");
    printTreeInorder(v->right);
    printf(")");
}
```

the Txt file that runs as intended:
{
words are in this test files for testing purpse 
of transfering strings into data structures.
}

however if i change it to this i get segmentation fault:
{
words are in this test files for testing purpse 
of transfering strings into data structures.
& 
words are in this test files for testing purpse 
of transfering strings into data structures.
}

Comment: There are lots and lots of opportunities to trip up your heroic program outside of what you have shown here. Please make a [mcve].

Comment: Also add a sample input which works and one which does not work, aka "small" and "big".

Comment: @Yunnosch ^^ it is so well said

Comment: Trailing spaces in a `scanf` format is usually a bad idea, since it means the function must read until it hits a non-space character.

Comment: `fscanf(fp,"%s \n",word) != EOF` can write out of bound if any line of the text is greater than `MAX`, use `fgets`.

Comment: Also be careful about the placement of the `fclose` call. Currently it can be called with a null pointer.

Comment: Please note: I get a compiler warning *C4717: 'searchforexist': recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow*

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to to use a gdb/lldb.

I compiled your code, and debugged:

```
$ g++ -g -ggdb test.cc
$ lldb a.out
(lldb) r
Process 83386 launched: '/path/to/a.out' (x86_64)
Process 83386 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000ec1 a.out`searchforexist(root=0x0000000000000000, key="<link") at test.cc:104
   101  void searchforexist(TreeNode *root, char *key)
   102  {
   103     if (root == NULL || root->key == key)
-> 104         root->freq ++;
   105
   106
   107      if (root->key < key)
Target 0: (a.out) stopped.
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)
  * frame #0: 0x0000000100000ec1 a.out`searchforexist(root=0x0000000000000000, key="<link") at test.cc:104
    frame #1: 0x0000000100000eed a.out`searchforexist(root=0x0000000100102e50, key="<link") at test.cc:108
    frame #2: 0x0000000100000efe a.out`searchforexist(root=0x0000000100102b00, key="<link") at test.cc:111
    frame #3: 0x0000000100000d34 a.out`insertItem(root=0x0000000100102b00, gword="<link") at test.cc:78
    frame #4: 0x0000000100000c28 a.out`main at test.cc:47
(lldb)
```

I think this error message represented enough information.

---

I made a few modification. Just make it worked.

I could not image the pervious one could worked unless each of the word is short and unique.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct listNode {
  int id;
  struct listNode *next;
} ListNode;

typedef struct treeNode {
  char *word;
  char *key;
  int freq;
  ListNode *head;
  struct treeNode *left;
  struct treeNode *right;
} TreeNode;

TreeNode *insertItem(TreeNode *root, char *gword);
void printTreeInorder(TreeNode *v);
void searchforexist(TreeNode *root, char *key);
void freeNodes(TreeNode *root);

#define MAX 25
int main() {
  char word[MAX];
  TreeNode *root = NULL;

  FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");

  memset(word, 0, MAX);
  if (fp != NULL) {
    // why fsanf("%s \n") ? is this a very special format?
    while (fscanf(fp, "%24s \n", word) != EOF) {
      // fprintf(stderr, "got: [%s]\n", word);
      root = insertItem(root, word);

      if (strcmp(word, "eof") == 0) break;
    }

    fclose(fp);
  }

  printTreeInorder(root);
  printf("\n");

  freeNodes(root);
  return 0;
}

TreeNode *insertItem(TreeNode *root, char *gword) {
  TreeNode *v = root;
  TreeNode *pv = NULL;
  while (v != NULL) {
    pv = v;
    int comp = strcmp(gword, v->word);
    if (comp < 0) {
      v = v->left;
    } else if (comp > 0) {
      v = v->right;
    } else {
      // char *key = v->word;
      char *word = v->word;
      searchforexist(root, word);
      return root;
    }
  }

  TreeNode *tmp = (TreeNode *)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
  // why both key and word?
  tmp->word = strdup(gword);
  tmp->left = tmp->right = NULL;
  tmp->freq = 1;

  if (root != NULL) {
    if (strcmp(gword, pv->word) < 0) {
      pv->left = tmp;
    } else {
      pv->right = tmp;
    }
  } else
    root = tmp;

  return root;
}

void searchforexist(TreeNode *root, char *word) {
  if(root == NULL) {
    return;
  }

  int comp = strcmp(word, root->word);

  if(comp == 0) {
    root->freq++;
  } else {
    searchforexist(comp < 0 ? root->left : root->right , word);
  }

}

void printTreeInorder(TreeNode *v) {
    if (v==NULL) return;

    printf("(");
    printTreeInorder(v->left);
    printf(")");

    printf(" %.4s ", v->word);

    printf("(");
    printTreeInorder(v->right);
    printf(")");
}

void freeNodes(TreeNode *root) {
  if (root == NULL) {
    return;
  }
  freeNodes(root->left);
  freeNodes(root->right);

  if(root->word != NULL) free(root->word);
  if(root->key != NULL) free(root->key);
  free(root);
  return;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that no code should ever look like `if(ptr == NULL . . . ) ptr->anything;`

Comment: Dear @TimRandall , you are right. and there are a lot of problems of this code. In this case, the direct problem raised this segment fault is the bad access to a null pointer. Just wanna to introduce a method to debug the code easier,

Comment: and then, we can talk about something else in high level